# Dictionary keys match on list; get key/value pair

Tags: python, list, dictionary, match, key

In python... I have a list of elements 'my_list', and a dictionary 'my_dict' where some keys match in 'my_list'.

I would like to search the dictionary and retrieve key/value pairs for the keys matching the 'my_list' elements.

I tried this...

```
    if any(x in my_dict for x in my_list):
          print set(my_list)&set(my_dict)
```

But it doesn't do the job.

Comment: Please don't name your variables `list` or `dict`. It confuses the heck out of people (and possibly then Python interpreter, too, if you're not careful).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

(I renamed `list` to `my_list` and `dict` to `my_dict` to avoid the conflict with the type names.)

For better performance, you should iterate over the list and check for membership in the dictionary:

```
for k in my_list:
    if k in my_dict:
        print(k, my_dict[k])
```

If you want to create a new dictionary from these key-value pairs, use

```
new_dict = {k: my_dict[k] for k in my_list if k in my_dict}
```

Comment: adding `my_dict.keys()` would make it much faster, as it would only search the `keys` in the `dict`. Or to search in values just use `my_dict.values()`

Answer (score 16):

Don't use `dict` and `list` as variable names. They shadow the built-in functions. Assuming list `l` and dictionary `d`:

```
kv = [(k, d[k]) for k in l if k in d]
```

Answer (score 13):

```
 new_dict = dict((k, v) for k, v in dict.iteritems() if k in list)
```

Turning list into a set `set(list)` *may* yield a noticeable speed increase

Comment: Note that `if k in list` will be `O(n)`.

Comment: Yeah; I was conveniently ignoring that for the sake of simplicity

Comment: hehe; I lost an upvote. Seems a bit harsh; There is merit in _deliberately_ providing a simple answer to a simple question.

Comment: dict.iteritems() would be preferable to dict.items().

Comment: Rob: The point is that the efficient solution is just as simple.

Comment: In this case I agree, it is _almost_ as simple. Kind of depends on the context of the OP's question but given the paucity of details, I concede my answer should be ignored :)

Comment: my_dict.iteritems() is preferable in that it combines the key and valye lookup into one call.

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
mydict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
mykeys = ['three', 'one','ten']
newList={k:mydict[k] for k in mykeys if k in mydict}
print newList
{'three': 3, 'one': 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about `print([kv for kv in dict.items() if kv[0] in list])`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one line solution for that

```
{i:my_dict[i] for i in set(my_dict.keys()).intersection(set(my_list))}
```