# How to copy dictionairy using list of keys

Tags: python, dictionary

What is a convenient way of making a copy of a dictionary and only keep entries that are relevant to you?

Here I try to create a dictionary `newdict`:

```
mydict = {'A':'dog',
           'B':'cat',
           'C':'mouse'}

list_of_keys = ['A', 'B']
newdict = mydict[list_of_keys]
```

This syntax does not work. How would I create `newdict` which looks like this:

`newdict{'A':'dog', 'B':'cat'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this, here's the source: [Dictionary keys match on list; get key/value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505008/dictionary-keys-match-on-list-get-key-value-pair)

```
mydict = {'A':'dog',
           'B':'cat',
           'C':'mouse'}

list_of_keys = ['A', 'B']

new_dict = {k: mydict[k] for k in list_of_keys if k in mydict}

print(new_dict) //output: {'A': 'dog', 'B': 'cat'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dict comprehension like this -

```
new_dict = {key : value for key, value in mydict.items() if key in list_of_keys}
```